# Inerfaces difference in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a couple of interfaces:

```
interface ISubstitution {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   date: string;
   subject: number;
   new: string;
   group: number;
   form: boolean;
}

interface ISubstitutionHot {
  new: string;
  group: number;
  form: boolean;
}
```

Corresponding its is one object by interface type:

```
public a: any;
a = <ISubstitution> {
       id: 1,
       name:"O",
       date: "2018-01-1",
       subject: "M",
       new: "A", 
       group: 1,
       form: true
}
```

Note `ISubstitutionHot` extends `ISubstitution`.

So, in conclusion I have filled object `a`.

How to take difference between objects/interfaces like:

```
let c = <a>ISubstitution / <b>ISubstitutionHot;
```

To retrieve only fields from object `a` that there are in interface `ISubstitutionHot`? It should return me:

```
c = {
new: "A", 
group: 1,
form: true
}
```

Is it possible in TypeScript?

Comment: No, because typescript interfaces don't exist at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Types and interfaces in TypeScript only exist at compile/design time, and are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when code is compiled to JavaScript.  That means that the only way you can make something happen at runtime is if you place the information you need in a *value* and not just a *type*.  Here's one way to proceed:

First, define `hotKeys`, an array of the strings `"new"`, `"group"`, and `"form"`.  The function `keyArray()` is just a helper function that allows TypeScript to infer the literal types instead of just `string[]`:

```
const keyArray = <K extends string>(...keys: K[]) => keys;
const hotKeys = keyArray('new', 'group', 'form');
type HotKeys = typeof hotKeys[number];
```

If you inspect it, `hotKeys` is of type `('new' | 'group' | 'form')[]`, and therefore `HotKeys` is `'new' | 'group' | 'form'`.

Now we will define the `pick()` function, which takes an object and an array of keys from that object, and returns another object with just the properties corresponding to those keys.  Like this:

```
function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Pick<T, K> {
  const ret = {} as Pick<T, K>; // empty to start
  keys.forEach(k => ret[k] = obj[k]); // copy some properties
  return ret; 
}
```

This is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function which uses the built-in `Pick` [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).

If you want, you can either define `ISubstitutionHot` as an interface the way you have, or you can define it in terms of `ISubstitution` and `HotKeys` like this:

```
type ISubstitutionHot = Pick<ISubstitution, HotKeys>; 
// { new: string; group: number; form: boolean; }
```

Finally, let's write the function which converts an `ISubstitution` to an `ISubtitutionHot`:

```
function iSubstitutionHot(iSub: ISubstitution): ISubstitutionHot {
  return pick(iSub, hotKeys);
}
```

The fact that the above function type checks with no errors is an indication that we're on the right track.

Okay, let's try it:

```
const a: ISubstitution = {
  id: 1,
  name: "O",
  date: "2018-01-1",
  subject: 1, // "M" <-- number!
  new: "A",
  group: 1,
  form: true
}

let c = iSubstitutionHot(a);
console.log(c); // { new: "A", group: 1, form: true }
```

It works!  You can see the code in action [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20ISubstitution%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subject%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20form%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20keyArray%20%3D%20%3CK%20extends%20string%3E%28...keys%3A%20K%5B%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20keys%0D%0Aconst%20hotKeys%20%3D%20keyArray%28%27new%27%2C%20%27group%27%2C%20%27form%27%29%3B%0D%0Atype%20HotKeys%20%3D%20typeof%20hotKeys%5Bnumber%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20pick%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%28obj%3A%20T%2C%20keys%3A%20K%5B%5D%29%3A%20Pick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20ret%20%3D%20%7B%7D%20as%20Pick%3CT%2C%20K%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20keys.forEach%28k%20%3D%3E%20ret%5Bk%5D%20%3D%20obj%5Bk%5D%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20ret%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ISubstitutionHot%20%3D%20Pick%3CISubstitution%2C%20HotKeys%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20iSubstitutionHot%28iSub%3A%20ISubstitution%29%3A%20ISubstitutionHot%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20pick%28iSub%2C%20hotKeys%29%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%3A%20ISubstitution%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22O%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20%222018-01-1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20subject%3A%201%2C%20%2F%2F%20%22M%22%20%3C--%20number%21%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%3A%20%22A%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20group%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20form%3A%20true%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20c%20%3D%20iSubstitutionHot%28a%29%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log%28c%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20new%3A%20%22A%22%2C%20group%3A%201%2C%20form%3A%20true%20%7D).  Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: In general, I would avoid this, and embrace duck typing.